# Rodar uma instãncia do scheduler num ambiente clusterizado

Tags: ejb, scheduler

Tenho um projeto  `EJB` que grava um registro no banco de 5 em 5 minutos. Para isso estou usando a anotação  `@Schedule`.

Para o cluster funcionar, preciso subir a aplicação nos dois nodes do  `JBoss` (nodeA e nodeB), o scheduler acaba rodando nos dois nodes, causando duplicidade no registro do banco.

Já pesquisei bastante e ainda não encontrei a solução.

Fiz um projeto bem simples usando o  `Quartz`, mas acabei desistindo pois não consigo usar  `@PersistenceContext` para obter o  `entityManager` e também acabei desistindo por enquanto do  `Quartz`, pois tenho várias aplicações prontas usando o  `@Schedule` do  `EJB`, aí vou precisar migrar todas aplicações para o  `Quartz`. Se só o  `Quartz` resolver, então não terei escolha.

Afinal, há algum jeito de usar o  `@Scheduler` no ambiente clusterizado rodando apenas um dos  `schedulers` do  `cluster`?